# Azure download blob using url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, blob

I have created an Azure Cloud Service project on Visual Studio. I've been able to upload my files in the azure blob storage. What i need is, when click on a button, it will return me the URL of the uploaded blob such as http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/conversions/filename.extension

In my View, i've done the following:

```html
<div class="table">
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>ConversionID</th>
                <th>Actual Format</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Download</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FileName</td>
                <td>@item.ConversionID</td>
                <td>@item.Format</td>
                <td>@item.Status</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Download.aspx?conversionID=@item.ConversionID">
                        <span class="DownloadListItem">
                            <b>Download<b>
                        </span>
                    </a>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

My Download.aspx.cs:

```
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rawId = Request.QueryString["ConversionID"];
        int converionID;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawId) && int.TryParse(rawId, out converionID))
        {
          var v = db.Conversions.Where(a => a.ConversionID.Equals(converionID));  

            if (v != null)
            {
                //return ConversionURL
            }   
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Fail("ERROR : We should never get to AddToCart.aspx without a ConversionID.");
            throw new Exception("ERROR : It is illegal to load AddToCart.aspx without setting a ConversionID.");
        }
    }
```

How can i return the ConversionURL in my code?

**EDIT**

When i upload a file, i upload the file and its content in Azure Blob Storage, but i also store on a SQL server database the ConversionID and ConversionURL of the uploaded file.

Comment: You need to tell us how your conversionID is related to the file you uploaded.

Comment: Just edited my post!

Answer (score 2):

Once you upload your blob, you have the access to the [Uri property of cloud blob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.uri.aspx). Save that after your upload to the database and return once you gets the ConversionId.

```
        blob.UploadFromFile(...);
        var blobUrl = blob.Uri;
```